# shell script that will combine two files into another file?

Tags: bash, unix

Contents of input file 1:

```
David 734.838.9801
Roberto 313.123.4567
Sally 248.344.5576
Mary 313.449.1390
Ted 248.496.2207
Alice 616.556.4458
Frank 634.296.1259
```

Contents of input file 2:

```
Roberto Tuesday 2
Sally Monday 8
Ted Sunday 16
Alice Wednesday 23
David Thursday 10
Mary Saturday 14
Frank Friday 15
```

How can i make a bash script combining the two files making it look like below  using output redirection within the script and using loop structure? so i opened a new vi file called output.sh and i inserted join inputfile1 inputfile2 > output.sh. when i try to run it with bash output.sh, it tells me file 1 is not in sorted order and same with two then ted command not found alice command not found which are the names.

```
Name        On-Call         Phone           Start Time
Sally       Monday          248.344.5576        8am
Roberto     Tuesday         313.123.4567        2am
Alice       Wednesday       616.556.4458        11pm
David       Thursday        734.838.9801        10am
Frank       Friday          634.296.1259        3pm
Mary        Saturday        313.449.1390        2pm
Ted     Sunday          248.496.2207        4pm
```

Comment: Numerous example would exist that `join` two files on a given field.  Did you try anything at all?

Comment: `How can i make a bash script combining the two files ...` -- By writing some code or by _outsourcing_ it.  You seem to have chosen to _crowdsource_ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, which help you to get the expected result.

```
echo  "Name\tOn-call\t\tPhone\t\tStart time" >anotherfile
while IFS=' ' read f1 f2;do
  while IFS=' ' read f3 f4 f5 ; do
    if [ $f1 = $f3 ] ; then
       if [ $f5 -gt 12 ] ; then
            echo "$f1\t$f4\t$f2\t `echo "$f5 - 12" | bc`pm" >>anotherfile.txt
       else
            echo  "$f1\t$f4\t$f2\t$f5 \bam" >>anotherfile.txt
       fi
    fi
  done <file2
done <file1
```

Comment: when i bash script.sh which is the vi file i put ur code in. it tells me command not found

Comment: this doesn't convert 24 hour format to AM and PM. Nor does it sort by day of the week as requested.

Comment: `echo "name\t...."` needs to be `echo -e "Name\t...` to print tabs

Comment: I corrected my mistake

Comment: @user3483718 Whether did you specified correct file name in done position.

Answer (score 0):

This combines the contents of on-call.txt and phone-number.txt files into an array. Additionally it converts 24Hr time format to AM and PM, then displays the output by day.

```
#!/bin/bash

Person=( $(cat phone.txt on-call.txt| egrep "[a-z]|[A-Z]"| sort| paste - -) )

echo -e "Name\tOn-Call\tPhone\tStart Time"
for day in Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saterday Sunday; do
    x=0
    z=0
    until [ $z = $(( ${#Person[@]} / 5 )) ]; do

            if [ $day = ${Person[$(($x + 3))]} ]; then
                    if [ ${Person[$(($x+4))]} -ge 13 ]; then
                            Person[$(($x+4))]="$(( ${Person[$(($x+4))]} - 12 ))pm"
                    else
                            Person[$(($x+4))]="${Person[$(($x+4))]}am"
                    fi
                    echo -e ${Person[$(($x+0))]}"\t"${Person[$(($x+3))]}"\t"${Person[$(($x+1))]}"\t"${Person[$(($x+4))]}
            fi

            let "x += 5"
            let z++
    done
done
```

Comment: i tried ur script am only getting Name on-call phone startime thats it

Comment: Sorry I dropped the output headers names during an edit. They are back.

Comment: i dont get it shouldnt i just used the join function. do i need all this code because all i need to do is vi file 1 and file 2 and then vi a script that joins those two files.

Comment: If you desire to order the output by day of the week as in your example output, then you should load the data into bash array

Comment: @user2383718 I was able to condense the code further. If you are able to use this, please mark as useful.